# CRON and page loaded JS

Tags: javascript, php, forms, cron

Hi i am having trouble with form submissions

the scenario is

i have already tried 
'5 * * * * wget -O - http://example.com/cron-page/ >/dev/null 2>&1' 
to perform the command as you may already see i am a novice when it comes to cron.

i got a page that loads a JS Script onto it that then performs a submittal action once the visitor loads the page and this will reload and keep updating data until there are no more entries needed to update. however i want to have a cron job load the page and do these actions every 5 minutes

is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 */5 * * * * wget -O - http://example.com/cron-page/ >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: have tried that doesnt seem to be working, will this command also load up the page with the JS script attached to it?

Comment: Before scheduling with CRON, manually access and check your PHP file, in which JS is loading?